# Why is the set containing a cell $(x, y)$ of sqr grid iff $\exists$ integers $a, b \geq 0$ satisfying $a\;xor\;b=x$ and $a+b=y$ a Sierpinski triangle?

Tags: boolean-algebra, fractals

Let G be a square grid. Let S be a set of cells from G. A cell $(u, v)$ from G is in S $\iff$ there exist two non-negative integers a and b satisfying $a \oplus b=u$ and $a+b=v$. Why is S a Sierpinski triangle?

Comment: Do you have a reference for this fact? Also, what is $a\oplus b$ in this context?

Comment: I'm not the questioner but I think it's bit-wise xor (mentioned in the title). I tested this with some code and certainly the Sierpinski triangle seems to appear there, I'm not sure if it **is** the Sierpinski triangle or whether the Sierpinski triangle is just part of it. Why are people downvoting?